# problem opening documents in document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, document-library

hi we cannot open the items in document library and must save them first then open it in sharepoint2010 what should we do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add PDF as allowed MIME type (recommended) or set *File Handling* to *Permissive* alltogether (not recommended).
Here is an article that covers this topic: [SharePoint: Browser File Handling Deep Dive](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8073.sharepoint-browser-file-handling-deep-dive.aspx)

And here's the Powershell script that allows you to add a MIME type to the list of allowed ones for a specific web application (taken from the article):

```
$mimeType = "application/pdf"             
Get-SPWebApplication |             
foreach-object             
{             
    # If the MIME Type is not already on the allowed list for the Web Application             
    if(!$_.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Contains($mimeType))             
    {             
        # Add the MIME type to the allowed list and update the Web Application             
        $_.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add($mimeType)             
        $_.Update()             
        Write-Host Added $mimeType to the allowed list for Web Application $_.Name             
    }             
    else             
    {             
        # The MIME type was already allowed - can't add. Inform user             
        Write-Host Skipped Web Application $_.Name - $mimeType was already allowed             
    }             
}
```

Please note that *.pdf is considered as potentially dangerous, that's why it won't open in the browser by default.